# Django MPTT: Как оптимально вывести все категории и статьи без SQL дублей?

Tags: django, queryset

Есть две модели:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
            'self',
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            related_name='children',
            db_index=True,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )

class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    rubric = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles')
```

Мне необходимо вывести дерево категорий и все статьи в этих категориях, делаю я это таким образом:

```
        <ul>
            {% recursetree object_list %}
            {% if node.is_active %}
            <li>
                <strong>Категория</strong>
                {{ node.name }}
                <ul>
                        {% for article in node.articles.all %}
                        <li>{{ article.name }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endrecursetree %}
        </ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это строчка `{% for article in node.articles.all %}` делает запрос в базу, сколько категорий столько и будет запросов. Как правильно объединить в один запрос?

Answer (score 0):

К object_list в вашей вьюхе примените select_related("articles")